# Primes $p$ and $q$ such that $3p^{q-1}+1$ divides $11^p+17^p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

From the Balkan Mathematics Olympiad 2018:

> Find all prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $3p^{q-1}+1$ divides $11^p+17^p$.

I started using Fermat's Little Theorem, which states that $a^{p-1}-1$ is divisible by $p$ if $p$ is a prime. But I could not find any way to solve the problem.

Any suggestions, please.

Comment: How? Can you explain it .. pls.

Comment: Yaa... I had put the wrong question.. Now i have edited it.. it is right now

Comment: Ok so now $p=q=3$ is a solution

Comment: $(3, 2), (3, 3), (103, 2)$ at least

Comment: Did you try to compute $11^p$ and $17^q$ modulo $3 p^{q-1} + 1$?

Comment: Yaa...@MaximilianJanisch it is one of the solution .. but how did u get it?

Comment: How did you get it @AlexeyBurdin

Comment: How to do it? I rather look puzzled.. @OlivierRoche

Comment: Maybe the pairs mentioned by @AlexeyBurdin are the only solutions

Comment: @AnkanG.[brute-force](https://tio.run/##JZLNbsIwEITvPIUvlZIQpNi7zs@Bd@COOKA2qJEKMSE98PTpfu4h@zPrjGdHTu/1e36EQ3qn97alZbqPr@M51E5qF2vX1c57@6zz1EPtgtXBshguhqllNUytjvxls9aw1vrOcmdYZ1hvubc8wNNA2sDa5HbgHtpAK/nKXDFQQgSLYC3nYPddlsW0ZzrkAJbvGBCL@pAlwxxCXoAW5oD2EHNgCnNoGSA8dGAwhz7vbEGQK5AKcgVTJDuBXNEcMAcnBCsEpYJSQalAJfggiFSMUNZXvNWQzcwBSxGp2VxIFZGKt4pShVkh1Z6K9ZWlI8ZGSCN8kfWj@svutsx3N63jss7zz8tN9zQvq0vL/PX7ubrry5129gIea3EuUv0s3W1enBVuerhT8f826mVM43U9htJNN1d4X1Vp77uqepYfhVSpqornwZd7Xx6PzaXctj8)

Comment: It should be $17^p$ not $17^q$, See [here](https://bmo2018.dms.rs/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/BMOproblems2018_English.pdf), Official solution is [here](https://bmo2018.dms.rs/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Solutions.pdf)

Comment: Dear @AlexeyBurdin I  think the the answer is right.. but how to attempt it ?? It is a subjective exam.. how to show it??

Comment: It really helps to get the right question.

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT:

$11^p≡11 mod p=k_1 .p + 11$

$17^p≡17 mod p=K_2 .p + 17$

$11^q≡11 mod q=k_3 .q + 11$

$17^p≡17 mod q=K_4 .q + 17$

Summing these relations we get:

$(11^p+17^q)+(11^q+17^p)=56+(k_1+k_2)p+(k_3+k_4)q$

P and q are primes, therefore numbers $(11^p+17^q)$ , $(11^q+17^p)$,  $3.p^{q-1} +1$, $(k_1+k_2)$ and $(k_3+k_4)$ must have common divisors like$ 2, 4, 7, 8, 14, 28 and 56$.

Now $3.p^{q-1}+1$ ≤ $(11^p+17^q)= 56 m$; $m∈N$. This is the condition of question. For example with p=q=3 we get 28. I think better question is: Find all possible divisors of $11^p+17^q$ and $3p^{q-1}+1$

Comment: I got it.. Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

**hint**
Assume $ p\ne q$ and both $\ne 11,17$.

then by Euler's theorem

$$3p^{q-1}+1 \equiv 4 \mod q$$
and
$$11^p+17^p \equiv 11+17 \mod p$$

Comment: Can it be done by this way.... I mean fully.?

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not clear to me how that's a hint towards a solution.