# Balkan MO :Find all possible primes $p$ and $q$ such that $3p^{q-1}+1$ divides $11^p+17^p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find all possible primes $p$ and $q$ such that $3p^{q-1}+1$ divides $11^p+17^p$.

This problem was posted 2 times in MSE, but was never solved. Can someone help me?

I am supposed to use orders and mods

Comment: cf. [Primes $p$ and $q$ such that $3p^{q-1}+1$ divides $11^p+17^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3452209/602049).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Primes $p$ and $q$ such that $3p^{q-1}+1$ divides $11^p+17^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452209/primes-p-and-q-such-that-3pq-11-divides-11p17p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer with hidden hints. We assume that $3p^{q-1} +1$ divides $11^p+17^p$ for some primes $p$ and $q$.

- If $p=2$, it is not possible. (Brute force)

> For $p=2$ we have $11^2+17^2 = 410$ whose factors are $1,2,5,10,41,82,205,410$. If $3 \times 2^{q-1}+1$ is a factor then that factor is of the form $3k+1$ i.e. that factor can only be $1,10,82$ or $204$, but in each case $k \neq 2^{q-1}$ for $q$ prime.

- Now for $p>2$, $ 8 \nmid 11^p+17^p$.

> Since $p$ is odd, $$11^p + 17^p \equiv 3^p+1 \equiv 3+1\equiv 4 \mod 8$$

- Let $r$ be an odd prime divisor of $3p^{q-1}+1$. Then $r \notin \{3,11,17\}$.

> Of course $r \neq 3$,otherwise it cannot divide a number of the form $3k+1$. But $3p^{q-1}+1$ divides $11^p+17^p$ so if $r$ divides the RHS then it cannot divide either of $11^p$ or $17^p$ as it would have to divide the other too, but both are coprime. Consequently $r \neq 11,17$.

- There is a $b$ such that $17b \equiv 1 \mod r$ , by Bezout's theorem. Show that $ord_r(11b) \in \{2,2p\}$.

> If $17b \equiv 1 \mod r$ then $b^p(11^p+17^p) \equiv (11b)^p +1\mod r$, but $r$ divides $11^p+17^p$ so $(11b)^p + 1$ is a multiple of $r$, and therefore $(11b)^{2p}-1$ is a multiple of $r$. Therefore $ord_r(11b)$ divides $2p$, but is not equal to $1$ obviously.

- Let $ord_r(11b) = 2$. Then $r=7$.

> If so then $r$ divides $(11b)^2-1$, but then it also divides $(11b)^2 - (17b)^2$, and because it is coprime to $b$ is a divisor of $11^2-17^2 = -168$. Since $r \neq 3$ we must have $r=7$.

- If $ord_r(11b) = 2p$ then $2p$ divides $r-1$, by Fermat's little theorem. Hence we may write the prime decomposition $$
  3p^{q-1}+1 = 2^{\alpha}7^{\beta}p_1^{\gamma_1}...p_k^{\gamma_k}
  $$ where $p_i \neq 2,7$ are prime factors with $p_i \equiv 1 \mod 2p$.
- We have $\beta \leq 1$, by observing that $\frac{11^p+17^p}{28}$ is not a multiple of $7$. (Hint : $11+17= 28$, so that fraction is definitely a natural number, but you can say more) Thus $\beta \leq 1$.

> The standard factorization $\frac{a^p-b^p}{a-b} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a^kb^{n-k}$ applies with $a=11,b=-17$ and we get using $11 \equiv 4$ and $17 \equiv -4$ mod $7$, that $\frac{11^p+17^p}{28} \equiv p4^{p-1}$ mod $7$, and $p \neq 7$(why?)

- If $q=2$, then the problem has no solutions.

> If so then $3p+1 = 2^{\alpha}7^{\beta}p_1^{\gamma_1}...p_k^{\gamma_k}$, but each of the $p_i$ is at least $2p+1$ which is more than half $3p+1$. Therefore no $p_i$ exist. By the existing bounds on $\alpha,\beta$ there are only the candidates $3p+1 = 2,4,14,28$, none of which work.

- If $q>2$, then $\alpha = 2$ and $p=3$.

> If $q>2$, then $p^{q-1} \equiv 1 \mod 4$ since $q-1$ is even, hence $3p^{q-1} +1$ is a multiple of $4$, so $\alpha = 2$. Finally, $2^{\alpha}7^{\beta} p_1^{\gamma_1}...p_k^{\gamma_k}$ is congruent to $4$ or $28$ modulo $p$, because the $p_i$ are all congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. But $3p^{q-1}+1$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. As these are equal, we get that either $1-4$ or $1-28$ is a multiple of $p$. Either way $p=3$.

- See that $q=3$ must happen if $p=3$.

> Well, we have $11^3+17^3= 6244 = 2^2 \times 7 \times 223$, so if $3 \times 3^{q-1} +1$ is a multiple of $6244$, then this is the same as saying $3^q+1$ is a multiple of $6244$, and therefore $q=3$ is the only option since $q=1,2,4,...,7$ don't work and $q=8$ is too large.

- Thus $p=q=3$ is the only solution.

Comment: I read your answer, and it makes use of math that I have not yet mastered, but it let me see an interesting approach. However, my approach might be deficient in some way, so I ask you if that is the case. Let $3p^{q-1}=x$. After eliminating $p=2$, we know that $p$ is odd. So we want to solve $11^p+17^p \equiv 0 \bmod x$. The obvious solution for odd $p$ is $11\equiv -17 \bmod x$ which yields $x=28$ from which $p=q=3$. Is this reasoning insufficient?

Comment: @KeithBackman just going to sleep will reply to you in the morn definitely

Comment: @KeithBackman Why does $11^p + 17^p \equiv 0 \mod x$ imply that $11 \equiv -17 \mod x$? The point is that $p$ is varying : one possibility is that $11 \equiv - 17 \mod x$, but $x$ just needs to work for one $p$. For example, $11^5 + 17^5 \equiv 0 \mod x$ where $x = 11^5 + 17^5$, so what cannot be done is skip to this step directly.

Comment: Certainly, for odd $p$, **if** $11\equiv -17 \bmod x$, **then** $11^p+17^p \equiv 0 \bmod x$, because $(-17)^{2k+1}+(17)^{2k+1}=0$. I think your point is that I'm missing an "**only if**" implication ruling out other possibilities. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @KeithBackman You have spotted the issue correctly, and you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

Due to Euler's criterion:

$A=3^{\frac{7-1}2=3}+1 \equiv 0 \ mod (7)$

$3\times 3^{q-1}+1\equiv 0 \ mod (7)$

These two relations give $p=q=3$

In this case $A=28$.

We check this with RHS, i.e $B=11^p+17^q$:

$11\equiv 4 \mod (7)$ , $\rightarrow 11^p \equiv 4^p \mod (7)=7a+4^p$

$17 \equiv 3 \ mod (7)$, $\rightarrow 17^q\equiv 3^q \ mod (7)=7b+3^q$

$17^q$ and $3^q$ are odd so $7b$ is even, therefore:

$17^q=14 b_1+3^q$

⇒ $11^p+13^q=7a+7b+4^p+3^q$

$11^p+17^q$ and $4^p+3^q$ are odd so $7a+7b$ must be even; $7b=14b_1$ is even, so $7a$ must also be even, let $7a=14a_1$, so we have:

$11^p+17^q=14(a_1+b_1)+4^p+3^q$

$4^p+3^q=(7-3)^p+3^q= 7t -3^p+3^q$

We need $11^p+11^q\equiv (4^p+3^q)\equiv 0 \ mod (7)$

This is only possible if $p=q$ such that:

$4^p+3^q=(7-3)^p+3^q= 7t +(-3^p+3^q=0)=7t$

Now if $p=q=3$ then $14a_1+14b_1=28 k$, because:

$11^3+17^3=223\times 28$

Hence $A=28\big|B$

That is $p=q=3$ can be a solution.